# Script is causing error

Tags: matlab

I have a piece of code that is being repeated in several routines, however I cannot make a function of it since it should changes inputs which is varargin. So the solution seems to put the piece of code in a m file and mention the name in calling routines. When I move the code to a file and call it, all the variables will be exactly the same way as if it is the body of code, however a calling function that comes after the script returns error: "Too many output arguments" when I put the script in the body, this error is not showing up anymore!!!

the code is:

```
function varargout=batchMean(@func,adrs,varargin)
% code I want to move to script file
grd=find(strcmp(varargin,'grid'));
grdfl=find(strcmp(varargin,'gridFile'));
if grd
    % If grid is provided in the arguments
    grid=varargin{grd+1};
    varargin(grd:grd+1)=[];
elseif grdfl
    grdFile=cellstr(ls([adrs varargin{grdfl+1} '*']));
    varargin(grdfl:grdfl+1)=[];
    if isempty(grdFile)
        error('Hall_lab:batchAV:argin', ...
              'Grid file mentioned in input could not be found');
    end
    [grid,err]=matRead([adrs grdFile{1}]);
    if err
        error('Hall_lab:batchAV:grid', ...
            'Could not read grid file');
    end
else
    % Reading grid file
    grdFile=cellstr(ls([adrs '*Grd.mat']));
    if isempty(grdFile)
        grdFile=cellstr(ls([adrs '*grd.mat']));
    end
    if length(grdFile)>1
        error('Hall_lab:batchAV:fileSet', ...
            'There is more than one file for grid');
    elseif isempty(grdFile{:});
        error('Hall_lab:batchAV:fileSet', ...
            'There is no file for grid');
    end
    [grid,err]=matRead([adrs grdFile{:}]);
    if err
        error('Hall_lab:batchAV:grid', ...
            'Could not read grid file');
    end
    files=setdiff(files,grdFile);
end
% end of code I want to move to script file
% calling the function
[varargout{1:outNums}]=func(grid,data,inf,varargin{:});

% actual function being called
function [ave]=meanPIV(~,data,~)
ave=mean(data,ndims(data));
end
```

Comment: your snippet is not very clear.. what is func? what is meanpiv? where do you use batchmean?

Comment: First: If you don't understand it you better just pass instead of downvoting.
1. func is a function handler,
2. meanPIV is just a function as CLEARLY defined at the end of the code.
3. Your question is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems batchmeans doesn't have an output. You are using varargout but you never set it (see an example here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html). And why do you modify varargin? Maybe your function should just be

```
 [grid,err] = batchMean(func,adrs,varargin)
```

Comment: The code was not fully included because it's long and rest of the code did not cause problem. I don't have problem with using varargout.
the code between two comments:
<% code I want to move to script file>
<% end of code I want to move to script file>
Show's why I want to modify varargin?

Comment: In matlab you can't pass arguments by reference ( except for handles), so when you are in a function you are not modify ng your input but a copy of it

Comment: That's just what I said in the question:
"I cannot make a function of it since it should changes inputs"